# How to get gfortran to do INTEGER - LOGICAL conversion

Tags: gfortran

According to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Implicitly-convert-LOGICAL-and-INTEGER-values.html#Implicitly-convert-LOGICAL-and-INTEGER-values), gfortran can do integer-logical conversion, but I'm getting this error:

```
                  if (.not.bDropped.and.(zz_unif01() .lt. (1 - (Test_Dru
                           1
Error: Operand of .not. operator at (1) is INTEGER(4)
```

I know it would be better to change the code from `.not.bDropped` to `(bDropped.eq.0)`, but that would not be simple because it's generated code.

I tried various `-std=xxx` flags but they made no difference.

Comment: Welcome to the World of Strong Typing! :) Tune your code generator. It's the only way.

Comment: @kemiisto: Grr... Yeah, that's what I'm having to do.

Answer (score 1):

The last line on the page you linked to reads

```
However, there is no implicit conversion of INTEGER values in if-statements, [...].
```

I'd guess that has something to do with it.

Edit: This seems not to be the entire truth. Simply doing `l1 = .not. 0` (when `l1` is a logical variable) gives the same error you received. So there is no implicit conversion in this case either.

Comment: i think it would be enough to use == if you want to consider it as a boolean 
like : 
do while(eof(1)== 0 ) or something like that